# Let X be a metric space and let $f : X\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function. Pick out the true statements

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $f : X\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function.
Pick out the true statements.
(a) $f$ always maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.
(b) If $X$ is compact, then $f$ always maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.
(c) If $X = R^n$, then $f$ always maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.

If $f$ is uniformly continuous then it maps a cauchy sequence to a cauchy sequence. So, a is not true and b is true. What about c?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function

Comment: Note that you have not actually proved that (a) is false. You need to exhibit a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $(x_k)$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb R^n$, then it is bounded and thus contained in a closed ball $B$ of finite radius. Now note that $B$ is compact in $\Bbb R^n$, and consider the function  $f$ restricted to $B$.